# How to create a file in remote server from local server?

Tags: shell, unix

can anyone tell me how can i store the names of a file that are in remote server to a file and then get the file that contains the name in local server?

there is a remote server where 5 files are present , say

```
a.txt
b.txt
c.txt
d.txt
e.txt
```

i want to write a script in my local server, which will connect to remote server and write all the filenames that are present in remote server (a.txt, b.txt, c.txt, d.txt, e.txt) in a temporary file say filenames.txt.

so filenames.txt will have the contents

```
cat filenames.txt
a.txt
b.txt
c.txt
d.txt
e.txt
```

after this i want to transfer this file (filenames.txt) to local server using any protocol?

please suggest ideas or scripts if it is possible.

thanks

Comment: Why do you need to create the list of file on remote server and then transfer that top local. why not create the file on local by looking at the remote server directly?

Answer (score 1):

if there are reasonably few files do this
 `ssh <server> ls <dirpath>/*.txt > result.txt`

where server is the address of the remote machine. I am assuming you are familiar with ssh.

ssh will execute `ls` which lists the files.

dirpath is where the files are located.

*.txt will filter out the text files.

The list will be returned via ssh to your machine

`> result.txt` will store the result to a file

Answer (score 1):

For the file to be created on the remote server:
`ssh <server> "ls /some/dir > output.txt"`, for the file to be created on your client machine:
`ssh <server> "ls /some/dir" > output.txt`.

Take a look at the quotes.

*hth*

Answer (score 0):

here is the [link](http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2013/05/retrieving-list-of-files-from-remote.html)

```
   #!/usr/bin/perl
     use strict;
     use warnings;
     use Net::FTP;
     my $ftp_site     = 'localhost';
     my $ftp_dir      = '/home/simon/software';
     my $ftp_user     = 'a_login_name';
     my $ftp_password = 'a_password';
     my $glob         = 'ex*';
     my @remote_files;
     my $ftp = Net::FTP-&gt;new($ftp_site) 
        or die "Could not connect to $ftp_site: $!";
     $ftp-&gt;login($ftp_user, $ftp_password) 
        or die "Could not login to $ftp_site with user $ftp_user: $!";
     $ftp-&gt;cwd($ftp_dir) 
        or die "Could not change remote working " . 
                 "directory to $ftp_dir on $ftp_site";
     @remote_files = $ftp-&gt;ls($glob);
     foreach my $file (@remote_files) {
         print "Saw: $file\n";
     }
     $ftp-&gt;quit();
```